# Javascript / RegEx not validating HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The issue is that it appears that non of my JavaScript is working and I've spent hours trying to figure out why, I can't find any obvious errors and I'm fairly new to JavaScript in general, but i'm trying to get JavaScript to validate the code in my form together with regEx and as of right now its not doing anything.

Heres the code for my Form:

```
<form action="ValideringVM.php" method="post" name="Registrer" onsubmit="return valider_alle()">
    <table> 
    <tr>

        <td><h3> Personalia:</h3> </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td> Fornavn: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Fornavn" onChange="valider_fornavn()"/></td>
        <td><div id="FeilFornavn">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Etternavn: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Etternavn" onChange="valider_etternavn()"/></td>
        <td><div id="FeilEtternavn">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Adresse: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Adresse" onChange="valider_adresse()"/></td> 
        <td><div id="FeilAdresse">*</div></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td> Postnr: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Postnr" onChange="valider_postnr()"/></td> 
        <td><div id="FeilPostnr">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Email: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Email" onChange="valider_email()"/></td> 
        <td><div id="FeilEmail">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Telefonnr: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Telefonnr" onChange="valider_telefonnr()"/></td> 
        <td><div id="FeilTelefonnr">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Lag Brukernavn: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Brukernavn" onChange="valider_brukernavn()"/></td> 
        <td><div id="Feilbruker">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Lag Passord: </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="Passord" onChange="valider_passord()"/></td> 
        <td><div id="Feilpassord">*</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send"/></td> 
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

and heres my Javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function valider_fornavn()
    {
        regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ .\- ](2,20)$/;
        OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Fornavn.value);
        if(!OK)
        {
            document.getElementById("FeilFornavn").innerHTML="Feil i Fornavn";
            return false;  
        } 
        document.getElementById("FeilFornavn").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }

    function valider_etternavn()
    {
        regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ .\- ](2,20)$/;
        OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Etternavn.value);
        if(!OK)
        {
            document.getElementById("FeilEtternavn").innerHTML="Feil i Etternavn";
            return false;  
        } 
        document.getElementById("FeilEtternavn").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }

    function valider_adresse()
    {
        regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ 0-9.\- ](2,30)$/;
        OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Adresse.value);
        if(!OK)
        {
            document.getElementById("FeilAdresse").innerHTML="Feil i Adresse";
            return false;  
        } 
        document.getElementById("FeilAdresse").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }

    function valider_postnr()
    {
        regEx = /^[0-9](4)$/;
        OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Postnr.value);
        if(!OK)
        {
            document.getElementById("FeilPostnr").innerHTML="Feil i Postnr";
            return false;  
        } 
        document.getElementById("FeilPostnr").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }

    function valider_email()
    {
        regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ 0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ 0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
        OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Email.value);
        if(!OK)
        {
            document.getElementById("FeilEmail").innerHTML="Feil i Email";
            return false;  
        } 
        document.getElementById("FeilEmail").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }

    function valider_telefonnr()
    {
        regEx = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
        OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Telefonnr.value);
        if(!OK)
        {
            document.getElementById("FeilTelefonnr").innerHTML="Feil i Telefonnummer";
            return false;  
        } 
        document.getElementById("FeilTelefonnr").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }

    function valider_brukernavn()
    {
      regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ 0-9](4,20)$/;  
      OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Brukernavn.value);
      if(!OK)
      {
          document.getElementById("Feilbruker").innerHTML="Feil i brukernavnet";
          return false;
      }    
      document.getElementById("FeilBruker").innerHTML="";
      return true;
    }


    function valider_passord()
    {
      regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ 0-9](4,20)$/;  
      OK = regEx.test(document.Registrer.Passord.value);
      if(!OK)
      {
          document.getElementById("FeilPassord").innerHTML="Feil i passordet";
          return false;
      }    
      document.getElementById("FeilPassord").innerHTML="";
      return true;
    }

   function valider_alle()
   {
      (e || window.event).preventDefault();
      FornavnOK = valider_fornavn();
      EtternavnOK = valider_etternavn();
      AdresseOK = valider_adresse();
      PostnrOK = valider_postnr();
      TelefonnrOK = valider_telefonnr();
      EmailOK = valider_email();
      BrukernavnOK = valider_brukernavn();
      PassordOK = valider_passord(); 

   }
   if(FornavnOK && EtternavnOK && AdresseOK && PostnrOK && TelefonnrOK && EmailOK && BrukernavnOK && PassordOK)
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }


    </script>
```

Comment: you will have to validate field-by-field and not the form.value, use a form validator plugin or sth similar to add validations per form field

Comment: I think this could be just a problem with the brackets. The function `valider_alle()` is closed right before the `if...else...` that would determine if the form validated or not. Move the bracket after the `else` and check if it works

Comment: As a recommendation: next time check the error console on the browser. All the errors above were listed in the console, and once fixed, the form validated without issues. Knowing how to debug is almost as important as knowing how to code.

Comment: It is very bad practice to use implicit global variables. Use *var* to keep variables local unless you really need globals (which you don't).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

last function `valider_alle` end brace is not set to its right place

```
 function valider_alle()
 {
      (e || window.event).preventDefault();
      FornavnOK = valider_fornavn();
      EtternavnOK = valider_etternavn();
      AdresseOK = valider_adresse();
      PostnrOK = valider_postnr();
      TelefonnrOK = valider_telefonnr();
      EmailOK = valider_email();
      BrukernavnOK = valider_brukernavn();
      PassordOK = valider_passord(); 

 //} this one must be at the end
 if(FornavnOK && EtternavnOK && AdresseOK && PostnrOK && TelefonnrOK && EmailOK && BrukernavnOK && PassordOK)
 {
       return true;
 }
 else
 {
       return false;
 }

}
```

and if you are ensuring that the length is between 2 and 20 like that:

```
regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ .\- ](2,20)$/;// ( and ) is not for length
```

it must be written:

```
regEx = /^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ .\- ]{2,20}$/;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up rewriting the code to jQuery and made it work, but thanks anyhow!